How to squeeze a cube without rigging
I want to make cubes like the one in the picture. Are there built in functions that allow me to make a much more symertical squeeze?
I am trying to squeeze the sides of the cube.


Have you tried the lattice modifier or simple deform modifier?



Select all edges of the cube
Set the crease to 1 (This makes them stay sharp with the subdiv modifier)
Add the Subdiv modifier. The higher the level the less noticeable the faces are in the curve. FOr better visibility, check all the display types next to the 'Subdivision' name in the modifier.
Add edge loops to the cube with Ctrl+R
Scale or manually modify the edge loops to affect the geometry.

If you are using more than 1 edge loop, you can also add a mirror modifier so you only need to adjust the loops on 1 side

I did not get it, I just got a regular cube, can you show me the steps in images?

This is a really cool step by step tutorial contained in your image! I upvoted already, but if you could spell out the text from the image as bullet points that would be an even better answer.

Thank you for your answer but please avoid text written inside images, always prefer typing it directly in the body of the post instead. Image content can't be indexed and thus can't be searched for nor readily found by anyone looking for solutions in the future. Updates are difficult because it can't be easily edited in case of mistakes, nor updated in case of future changes. It doesn't follow the fonts and style of the website automatically, and doesn't work with screen readers.

thank you so much
